# How do I compose data for JSON rendering in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to use Rails to generate the link to the page for my models before I `to_json` the info and send it to my Backbone template.

I tried this in my controller:

```
@events.map! { |event|  event.link = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.slug_events_path({year: event.start.year, month: event.start.month, day: event.start.day, slug: event.slug}) }
```

but `map!` is not a method for `ActiveRecord`.

I tried this in my model:

```
attr_accessor :link
def link
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.slug_events_path({year: self.start.year, month: self.start.month, day: self.start.day, slug: self.slug})
end
```

and though I can call it in rails console, it doesn't get processed in the `to_json` call.

I realize I could generate this link using JavaScript, but I would feel a lot more comfortable getting it from Rails.

Can someone please tell me how to generate new information, either in the model or in the controller, then have it included as a field that can be converted to JSON?

Comment: check ActiveModel::Serializers https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/active-model-serializers

Comment: Can I suggest you reword this question to. "How do I compose data for JSON rendering in rails?".

Comment: Thanks Stewart, that's much more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of effects here that spring from one root cause. The root cause is that your not using the V in MVC. In almost all cases paths and links should be generated in your view. Here your trying to generate them in your controller and then your model. I suggest using jbuilder. It comes with rails and is the place to handle this kind of logic. Think of Jbulder as views for json. Using jbuilder you can map your model fields and any links directly to a json object. You won't even have to call to_json anymore.

Comment: I was uneasy about doing this outside of the "V", so that's a great suggestion. So is the Seralizers gem. I'll look into them when I get home today.

Comment: I would not use the seralizers gem unless your writing to disk. If your presenting data via http rails has all of this built in. Good luck!

Comment: ActiveModel::Serializers is not for writing to disk. It's for generating json.  It's much faster than jbuilder, but has more configuration.

Comment: @Swards yes true. What I should have said is that it a lower level API. In the OP's case I would suggest using the higher level API until there is such a point where that API can no longer achieve what is required. From what I can see the OP should have no reason to access the Serializer directly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stewart here, but just to answer this question, I believe you can solve your issues with a couple tweaks:

```
# each, not map!
# add format to url params

@events.each { |event|  event.update_column(:link, Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.slug_events_path({year: event.start.year, month: event.start.month, day: event.start.day, slug: event.slug, :format => :json}) }
```

or

```
def link
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.slug_events_path({year: self.start.year, month: self.start.month, day: self.start.day, slug: self.slug, format: :json})
end
```